# Wpf Combobox selectedvalue trigger

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers

I am trying to change the visibility with a trigger when a particular value in a combobox is selected, and I got the following XAML

```
 <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding AccessControl.Credentials}" >
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>                              
                            <Grid  >                                  

                             <ComboBox  Name="chkFieldType"                                          
                                        SelectedValue="{Binding Path=ValueSourceType,Converter={StaticResource enumstringConv}}"
                                        SelectedValuePath="Tag" SelectionChanged="chkFieldType_SelectionChanged" >
                                           <ComboBoxItem Tag="User">User</ComboBoxItem>                                     
                                           <ComboBoxItem Tag="SessionCredential">Field</ComboBoxItem>
                                           <ComboBoxItem Tag="Inherit">From other Resource</ComboBoxItem>
                             </ComboBox>


                                    <Border " Visibility="Hidden">
                                        <Border.Resources>
                                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                                                <Style.Triggers>
                                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedValue, ElementName=chkFieldType}" Value="Inherit">
                                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                                    </DataTrigger>
                                                </Style.Triggers>
                                            </Style>
                                        </Border.Resources>
                                        <ComboBox/>                                         
                                    </Border>
```

In this case a border. The selected value is "Inherit" of type string but the border remainds hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up setting the visibility manually via the code behind when the selectedItem event is fired..

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem and found that you have to set the visibility property using the style only. So instead of having the initial visibility set with:

```
<Border Visibility="Hidden">
```

You should set the initial visibility using the style:

```
<Style TargetType="....">
   <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
   <Style.Triggers>
      ....
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

(I know it's kinda overdue but I thought maybe someone else might run into the same problem).

Answer (score 2):

Try SelectedItem.Tag or SelectedItem.Content instead of SelectedValue

Answer (score 1):

Set your binding on SelectedValue, not SelectedItem.SelectedValue. The way you currently have it, it is looking for ComboBoxItem.SelectedValue, which doesn't exist

```
<DataTrigger Value="Inherit" 
             Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedValue,
                               Converter={StaticResource enumstringConv}, 
                               ElementName=chkFieldType}">
```

Comment: it still dosen't work. Updated the question to reflect the latest code.

Comment: @Marcom I am guessing that it is comparing the string `Inherit` with the enum object which is used for SelectedValue. Add the Converter to your DataTrigger binding and it should fix it

Comment: nope, I tried the combobox selection changed in code behind and the selected value is of type string

Comment: @Marcon Did you try the format I posted in my edit? I am not positive if DataTriggers bind to the Converted value or the Original value.

Comment: yup i tried both anyway. Wpf is cool but frustrating in these situations!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you are putting the DataTrigger in Border.Resources.
Try putting the style in the window.resources, with a x:key in order to apply the style to the border.

I think that the border.resources can not access to a control "outside it's own resources context"

Answer (score 0):

SelectedItem and SelectedValue are two seperate properties on the ComboBox.
Since your ComboBoxItems are all strings you can change
`<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.SelectedValue, ElementName=chkFieldType}" Value="Inherit">`
to
`<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, ElementName=chkFieldType}" Value="Inherit">`

Comment: Still experiencing the same problem.

Comment: Are there any binding errors?  If not, try setting your binding to  `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, ElementName=chkFieldType, diagnostics:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}" Value="Inherit">` and adding the namespace `xmlns:diagnostics="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase"` to get more output.

Comment: nothing comes on the output. hmm so the trigger itself is the problem, not the binding

Comment: Would it work to use a normal trigger instead of a DataTrigger?  `<Trigger Property="SelectedItem" SourceName="chkFieldType" Value="Inherit">`